# IMAP PHP : How can I keep a unique ID to an email between sessions?

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm pulling emails from IMAP into my database, then, using my app, you're able to delete emails, download attachments, etc.

But to be able to do this, I need to store an ID of that email in my database, so I can access the live email via IMAP later.

**How can I get this id?** Is it possible? I've heard mixed answers.

Edit: I'm using Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `UID`, which references the same email between sessions.

(At least, as long as the `UIDVALIDITY` of the folder has not changed between sessions).